# Error for nested forms with has_one relationship - `@practitioner[user_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to create a nested form. `Practioner` has one `User`.

```
class Practitioner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  private

  def practitioner_params
    params.require(:practitioner).permit(user_attributes: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation])
  end

end
```

My form looks like this

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @practitioner], url: spree.admin_practitioners_url, method: :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>

    <%= user_fields.field_container :email, class: ['form-group'] do %>
      <%= user_fields.label :email, Spree.t(:email) %>
      <%= user_fields.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <%= error_message_on :user, :email %>
    <% end %>

    <%= user_fields.field_container :password, class: ['form-group'] do %>
      <%= user_fields.label :password, Spree.t(:password) %>
      <%= user_fields.password_field :password, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <%= error_message_on :user,:password %>
    <% end %>

    <%= user_fields.field_container :password, class: ['form-group'] do %>
      <%= user_fields.label :password_confirmation, Spree.t(:confirm_password) %>
      <%= user_fields.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'form-control' %>
      <%= error_message_on :user,:password_confirmation %>
    <% end %>

  <%end%>

  <%= f.field_container :name, class: ['form-group'] do %>
    <%= f.label :name, Spree.t(:name) %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'form-control' %>
    <%= error_message_on :practitioner, :name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.field_container :location, class: ['form-group'] do %>
    <%= f.label :location, Spree.t(:location) %>
    <%= f.text_field :location, :class => 'form-control' %>
    <%= f.error_message_on :location %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I am getting the below error. I am not sure why do I get that error.

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (`@practitioner[user_attributes]' is not allowed as an instance variable name):
        1: <%= f.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
        2:   <div data-hook="admin_user_form_fields" class="row">
        3:     <div class="col-md-6">
        4:       <%= user_fields.field_container :email, class: ['form-group'] do %>
        5:         <%= user_fields.label :email, Spree.t(:email) %>
        6:         <%= user_fields.email_field :email, :class => 'form-control' %>
        7:         <%= error_message_on :user, :email %>
```

If I change `<%= user_fields.field_container :email, class: ['form-group'] do %>` to `<%= f.field_container :email, class: ['form-group'] do %>`, the code works fine.

**EDIT**

Practioner Controller

```
class PractitionersController < ResourceController

  def new
    @practitioner = Practitioner.new
    @practitioner.build_user
  end

  def create
    @practitioner = Practitioner.new(permitted_resource_params)
    if @practitioner.save
      collection
      render :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: The only thing springing to mind is that your `@practitioner` object is not an instance of `Practitioner` class. Could you show your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Using `<%= f.error_message_on :field %>` (and not `<%= error_message_on :whatever, :field %>`, works for the parent object.
When inside `:fields_for`, only

`<%= error_message_on nested_f.object, :field %>`

seems to work for me (`nested_f` being the helper for the nested object, so in your case it would be

`<%= error_message_on user_fields.object, :email %>`).